# How to trigger a Hall of Monuments update

Tags: guild-wars

So I always thought that you just had to logout and login to get the website (http://hom.guildwars2.com/) to update.

I recently got my Elonian and Legendary Cartographers titles, but my HoM hasn't updated. I tried logging out and in a few times. Both yesterday and today, without any luck

Anyone know how long it take now, or if they've changed it? I'm worried that my points haven't been counted!

Comment: A potentially silly question, but did you remember to display the trophies ingame in your HoM?

Comment: Yeah, got them all dedicated. It should be on the titles monument

Comment: This is lies, I had not 'dedicated' the statues! D'oh, if you can pop a reply on to that effect FallenAngelEyes I'll accept that :)

Comment: Curses, missed your message. If you put an @ in front of my name, It'll notify me that you've responded. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically, this means you haven't yet dedicated the title to the Monument of Honor. Double check that you have actually done so. If, after dedicating the title, it is still not displaying, contact support.